# In CIRIquant output, which column shows the expression level of circular?

Tags: python

I am running `CIRIquant` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS following the instruction which indicated on https://ciriquant-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/de.html. I got .GTF file that contains detailed information of BSJ and FSJ reads of circRNAs and annotation of circRNA back-spliced regions.
In the following, I added a record of Circular RNA detected in .GTF file:

```
Chrom: chr1 

Type: circRNA
    
start: 1289228
    
End:  1289448
    
score:0.02  

Strand Information: -
    
circ_id: chr1:1289228|1289448   

circ_type   :exon
    
bsj: 1000

fsj: 515.000

junc_ratio: 0.004
    
gene_id: ENSG00000162576.12

gene_name: MXRA8

gene_type: protein_coding
```

I need to know which column of .GTF file indicates the expression count of circular detected?

I appreciate it if you share your comment with me.

Best Regards,